# Rails devise successful route on sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, routes

I'm still not understanding how to route to a users profile page after successful sign in with devise. I've read the other questions, googled, and gone through the devise docs and I still can't get it to work/understand.

In my routes

```
  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show'
```

I just want that page (with the users id myapp.com/profilename) to be the page users are redirected to when they sign in. I thought it would be an quick fix but, I've spent an excessive amount of time on this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: redirect url had to be written in controller action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use devise route helpers:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "profiles#show"
end
```

You would then use `current_user` instead of the `params[:id]` to figure out which profile to display.